# Unable call endpoint with Guzzle basic auth

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am trying to get an token from an API for codeship

```
 $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
 $response = $client->get('https://api.codeship.com/v2/auth/', [
     'auth' => [
         'xxxxxx@xxxxx.com',
         'xxxx'
     ],
 ]);
```

I am getting a 404 when hitting that URL, but I know the URL returns what I need as I can access it with the same creds in postman.

is there a way to prove it is sending the correct credentials?

Thanks

Comment: `GET https://api.codeship.com/v2/auth/` is not a valid endpoint, try `POST` method instead. read documentation: https://apidocs.codeship.com/v2/authentication/authenticate for more details.

Comment: <stares at the floor and contemplates why I do computing>. Thank you so much, completely forgot to check the VERB

Comment: @JaChNo I wrote codeship api client that might be useful for you. You can take a look at https://packagist.org/packages/thiagorb/codeship